# Texture mapping using Meshlab

Tags: graphics, mesh, meshlab

What is the easiest way of mapping a texture image on top of a bare 3D mesh using Meshlab, where the UV texture coordinates have not been specified?

Answer (score 9):

Filters -> Parameterization -> Per Triangle or flat plane (pick your preference)

Comment: In MeshLab 1.3.3, the commands are Filters > Texture > Parameterization: Trivial Per-Triangle or Parameterization: Flat Plane.